# incompatible pointer types assigning to NsObject from NSMutablearray in iOS7 warning

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsobject

Please Any one guide e how to rectify the warning,
I'm getting "incompatible pointer types assigning to nsobject from nsmutablearray" in iOS7 warning but in iOS6 its working fine.
Here I'm using like this,

```
NSObjectRef = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:NSMutableArrayData];
```

Comment: could you show type of `NSObjectRef` & `NSMutableArrayData`?

Comment: NSObjectRef is NSObject class,and NSMutableArrayData is mutablearray.

Comment: I've tested with same in Xcode 5 with deployment target 6.0. But I haven't get this issue?

Comment: Here my deployment target 5.1 but still warning is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning  because assign `NSMutableArray` as a `NSArray`. in Your case you are trying to set arrayWithArray `NSMutableArrayData` this is MutableArray but it must be `NSArray`.

[image: In Foundation.framwork]

[image] 
so +`NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)array;` it self say's set `NSArray` Object not `NSMutable Array` so just change the type of `NSMutableArrayData`  `NSMutable` to `NSArray` this warning goes away.

See the [`NSMutableArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.